# Running infinispan in docker on windows 10

Tags: docker, infinispan

I am trying to run the infinispan docker image on a Windows 10 machine with docker desktop for windows.

I wrote a small test Java program that connects to localhost:11222 using hotrod and accesses a cache.

The problem is that after the initial connect the client receives from the server a new address `172.17.0.3:11222` and it fails connecting to this address because this is a docker internal one and
docker desktop for windows cannot route messages directly to an internal container address.
Is there any workaround available in infinispan or on the windows machine ?

Comment: Can you put your `docker run` command, please? I need more information

Comment: Can you have a look into this: https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/infinispan/issues/31#issuecomment-254277272 ? As for the _Windows_ workaround..the bad news is you cannot run in the container in the host network.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to disable the handling of topology updates in your Hot Rod client:

```
infinispan.client.hotrod.client_intelligence=BASIC
```

More information about client intelligence [here](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/hotrod_java/hotrod_java.html#client_intelligence).

Note that this is not recommended in production: the client will ignore new servers coming up and it will keep trying to contact the servers in the initial server list long after they stop.